# Provider to use

Tags: asp.net, yetanotherforum

I created a new "ASP.NET Web Site (Razor)" in VS 2010. Some setup took place and now I have tables webpages_Membership, webpages_Roles and webpages_UsersInRole in my SQL Database. All worked fine -- in the web site, methods such as WebSecurity.UserExists worked. I assume this is using SimpleMembershipProvider.

Then, I decided to integrate yetanotherforum forums into my website. When I followed the directions on how to integrate yetanotherforum into an existing web site, there were two choices for provideds, YafMembershipProvider and AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. I defaulted the provider to AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

Now, I have a conflict -- if enableSimpleMembership is set to True, my existing code works, but forums don't work; otherwise, forum work, but my existing code doesn't. It appears I need to standardize on one provider...

Ideally I would like to have one set of membership tables. Does it mean that using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider is my only option? Are there any disadvantages, in general, of using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and not SimpleMembershipProvider?

Thanks